# Where to download older versions of Xamarin.iOS? In this specific case Xamarin.iOS 14.8.0.3

Tags: xamarin.ios, version

There is 14.2.0.12 at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios#downloads. But we cannot find 14.8.0.3.

By the way:
The newest version is not working for us because of this issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/302548/jsonserializer-throws-exception-in-xamarinios.html?childToView=306027#answer-306027

Answer (score 8):

For `xamarin.ios-14.8.0.3.pkg`:

https://aka.ms/xvs/pkg/macios/14.8.0.3

Answer (score 1):

This is what you might be looking for.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/releases/tag/xamarin-ios-14.8.0.3

Comment: Is there a compiled version? Something like xamarin-ios-14.8.0.3.dmg

Comment: Anyone? I don't know how to install the ZIP version.

Comment: Look at the answer from @Benl, that link works. I'm very frustrated because same serialization issue after upgrading VS2019 and xamarin.ios :(. He deserves the answer https://aka.ms/xvs/pkg/macios/14.8.0.3

Comment: I downgraded from 14.14 to 14.8.0.3 but still get the same error. Let me know if it works for you. I'll try downgrading to 14.2

Comment: Downgrading Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.8.7 did the trick for me after downgrading xamarin.ios to 14.8.0.3. I think i'll leave this setup as is. Don't want to lose more productivity days. Thanks MSFT :(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking, I have found a list of all Xamarin downloads in case you need to test on an older build:

https://www.cnblogs.com/jasondun/p/12629634.html